# What are some techniques used to speed up numerical solving (with NSolve)?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a rather complicated set of equation to solve, as shown in the code below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m[θ_] := √Abs[Sin[θ]]; 
F2[a_, θ_] := -15 m [θ] a Cot[m[θ] a]^3 + 15 Cot[m[θ] a ]^2 - 9 m [θ] a Cot[m[θ] a] + 4; (*-pi<theta<0*)
G2[a_, θ_] := -2 (m[θ] a Cot[m[θ] a] - 1);(*-pi<theta<0*)
U = 1;
NSolve[{
  (1 + Cos[θ]^2) F2[a, θ] == 9 U Cos[θ] Abs[Sin[θ]] G2[a, θ],
  Cos[θ] D[F2[a, θ], a] == 9 U Abs[Sin[θ]] D[G2[a, θ], a]}, {a, θ}]
```

Are there any methods to speed up the solving process for such complicated equations? Thank you

Comment: `NSolve` can do but little here. There are more variables than equations.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The only two unknown variables are `a` and `θ`, am I missing something out?

Comment: Are you solving over the real or the complex numbers?

Comment: real numbers @MichaelE2

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw three unknowns. Probably bad vision...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions are periodic in $\theta$, so we can limit the range. The plot shows there might be solutions $(a=0, \theta\in{\bf R)}$ or $(a\in{\bf R},\theta=0,\pi)$.

```
Periodic`PeriodicFunctionPeriod[sys /. Equal -> Subtract, θ]
(*  2 π  *)

Plot3D[
 sys /. Equal -> Subtract // Evaluate,
 {a, -1.2, 1.2}, {θ, -1, 7},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}},
 WorkingPrecision -> 32, Exclusions -> None,
 AxesLabel -> Automatic
 ]
Show[%, ViewPoint -> {-0.3, 0.4, -2.5}]
```

[image]
[image]

There are discontinuities in the formulas at $a=0$ and at $\theta=0,\pi$, but these can be removed to allow the solutions suggested above:

```
Limit[sys /. Equal -> Subtract, θ -> 0]
(*  {0, 0}  *)

Limit[sys /. Equal -> Subtract, θ -> Pi]
(*  {0, 0}  *)

Limit[sys /. Equal -> Subtract, a -> 0]
(*  {0, 0}  *)
```

It seems unlikely that there are other solutions, extrapolating from the graphs.

Comment: I suppose I should point out that by periodicity, the complete solution set includes $\theta=n\pi,\,n\in{\bf Z}$

Comment: *Update notice:* Somehow I left off $\theta=\pi$ originally.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A fast first look  provides `ContourPlot`:

```
eqn = {(1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2) F2[a, \[Theta]] ==9 U Cos[\[Theta]] Abs[Sin[\[Theta]]] G2[a, 
\[Theta]],Cos[\[Theta]] D[F2[a, \[Theta]], a] ==9 U Abs[Sin[\[Theta]]] D[G2[a, \[Theta]], a]}

ContourPlot[Evaluate[eqn], {a, -1 , 1 }, {\[Theta], -Pi, Pi},MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

Only at `\[Theta] == Pi||\[Theta] == -Pi` solutions might exist.

```
Limit[eqn, \[Theta] -> Pi] (*{35 a + 4 a^3 == 0, 35 a + 4 a^3 == 0}*) 
Limit[eqn, \[Theta] -> -Pi] (*{35 a + 4 a^3 == 0, 35 a + 4 a^3 == 0}*)
Solve[35 a + 4 a^3 == 0,a]
(*{{a -> 0}, {a -> -((I Sqrt[35])/2)}, {a -> (I Sqrt[35])/2}}*)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on how you arrived at the conclusion that only at theta=pi or theta=-pi solutions might exist? Thank you

Comment: In the plot you see the contours of the two equations. Points  of intersection are solutions